# How can I search for a variable in JavaScript (Firebug) by variable?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Is there any way in Firebug to search an active variable in JavaScript by its value?

Comment: I'm taking a guess here but can't you get variable data in Firebug's console? 

For example, type in your console :

$("#div)

If it exists, would return true. But  couldn't you call active variables in the same way?

Comment: @Trip:He's trying to search for a variable that has a given value.

Comment: Depends on your purpose. Cheat Engine could do this (latest versions are compatible with browsers), although it won't tell you the JS variable name, just the pointer in memory for that value and options to freeze/change it/and many others.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Comment: Are there any other extensions that can do this?